# Does the MySQL Command Line Interface (CLI) have connection environment variables?

Tags: mysql, environment-variables

Does the MySQL [Command Line Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) (CLI) or "shell" offer the ability to establish a connection using environment variables?  The PostgreSQL CLI `psql` [does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) via `libpq` with connection variables:

- `PGHOST`
- `PGPORT`
- `PGDATABASE`
- `PGUSER`
- `PGPASSWORD`

I know I can connect via command-line switches and a `~/my.cnf` file, but I'm wondering if there is an environment variable option analogous to the way `psql` works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for some of them: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/environment-variables.html

- `MYSQL_HOST`
- `MYSQL_TCP_PORT`
- There is no environment variable for the schema to use as the default schema. Client should specify that in the connection DSN, or else the [USE *schema*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) statement after connecting.
- There is no environment variable for the MySQL username.
- `MYSQL_PWD` but this is deprecated and insecure and will be removed in a future version of MySQL. It's insecure for PostgreSQL for the same reason: another user can view your client's environment variables using `ps`.

It's more secure to use `~/.my.cnf`, or you can specify a different option file to use. You can even store the username/password in an encrypted options file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html